# "sforce.connection.insert is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, custom-button, onclick

I am creating a button which creates new record in another object, i am using following javascript code

```
var curnc= new sforce.SObject("TR_Currency_Approval__c"); 
curnc.Name="{!TR_Currency__c.Name}"; 
curnc.Active__c={!TR_Currency__c.Active__c}; 
curnc.Description__c="{!TR_Currency__c.Description__c}"; 

var result=sforce.connection.insert([curnc]);


if(result[0].success == 'true'){
    alert('An New Opportunity with Name - ' + oppty.Name + ' was Created Successfully.');
}
```

I am getting sforce.connection.insert is not a  function error, could any one please help me to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

It's actually sforce.connection.create. You'll want to look at the [examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm) in the documentation. Here's the one for create:

```
var account = new sforce.SObject("Account");
account.Name = "my new account";
var result = sforce.connection.create([account]);

if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
  log("new account created with id " + result[0].id);
} else {
  log("failed to create account " + result[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion.  error was fixed but record is not creating on click,

Comment: @prasadnagamalli Check the browser console log for the error.